# Editing a XML file with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, shell, file, edit, xmlstarlet

I want to change a value in a XML file from shell. I have tried xmlstarlet and I tried different codes but it did not work.

***What I have tried / used:***

`xmlstarlet ed --ps --inplace --update 'core/databus/*/key[@name="SystemName"]/value[@type]/type' -v "test" template.xml`.

`xmlstarlet ed -u core/databus/key_value_mappings/key[@name="SystemName"]/value[@type="value"]/@value -v "test" template.xml`.

***Problem:***

When I used these codes nothing changed.

***What I would like:***

I would like to change the value SystemName. Technodrome to test123 for example.

### xml file

```
<core>
    <template>
        <!-- General information about the template -->
        <entity name="unit">S7-200</entity>
        <entity name="vendor">Siemens</entity>
        <entity name="description">Rough simulation of a basic Siemens S7-200 CPU with 2 slaves</entity>
        <entity name="protocols">HTTP, MODBUS, s7comm, SNMP</entity>
        <entity name="creator">the conpot team</entity>
    </template>
    <databus>
        <!-- Core value that can be retrieved from the databus by key -->
        <key_value_mappings>
            <key name="FacilityName">
                <value type="value">"Mouser Factory"</value>
            </key>
            <key name="SystemName">
                <value type="value">"Technodrome"</value>
            </key>
            <key name="SystemDescription">
                <value type="value">"Siemens, SIMATIC, S7-200"</value>
            </key>
            <key name="Uptime">
                <value type="function">conpot.emulators.misc.uptime.Uptime</value>
            </key>
            <key name="sysObjectID">
                <value type="value">"0.0"</value>
            </key>
            <key name="sysContact">
                <value type="value">"Siemens AG"</value>
            </key>
            <key name="sysName">
                <value type="value">"CP 443-1 EX40"</value>
            </key>
            <key name="sysLocation">
                <value type="value">"Venus"</value>
            </key>
            <key name="sysServices">
                <value type="value">"72"</value>
            </key>
            <key name="memoryModbusSlave0BlockA">
                <value type="value">[random.randint(0,1) for b in range(0,128)]</value>
            </key>
            <key name="memoryModbusSlave0BlockB">
                <value type="value">[random.randint(0,1) for b in range(0,32)]</value>
            </key>
            <key name="memoryModbusSlave255BlockA">
                <value type="value">[random.randint(0,1) for b in range(0,128)]</value>
            </key>
            <key name="memoryModbusSlave255BlockB">
                <value type="value">[random.randint(0,1) for b in range(0,32)]</value>
            </key>
            <key name="memoryModbusSlave1BlockA">
                <value type="value">[random.randint(0,1) for b in range(0,128)]</value>
            </key>
            <key name="memoryModbusSlave1BlockB">
                <value type="value">[random.randint(0,1) for b in range(0,32)]</value>
            </key>
            <key name="memoryModbusSlave2BlockC">
                <value type="value">[random.randint(0,1) for b in range(0,8)]</value>
            </key>
            <key name="memoryModbusSlave2BlockD">
                <value type="value">[0 for b in range(0,32)]</value>
            </key>
            <key name="Copyright">
                <value type="value">"Original Siemens Equipment"</value>
            </key>
            <key name="s7_id">
                <value type="value">"88111222"</value>
            </key>
            <key name="s7_module_type">
                <value type="value">"IM151-8 PN/DP CPU"</value>
            </key>
            <key name="empty">
                <value type="value">""</value>
            </key>
        </key_value_mappings>
    </databus>
</core>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the first XPath expression, you tried: it leads to an element name `type` which is child of an element `value` having an attribute `type`. Such an element does not exist, so nothing can be updated.

Try

```
xmlstarlet ed --ps -u 'core/databus/*/key[@name="SystemName"]/value' -v "test" template.xml
```

instead